# Localhost/~username/ not working for Mojave

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am new to web development and trying to setup php and mysql to start learning. I have followed this guide: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14/.

I have followed the guide step by step, but I can only access http://localhost:80 where I get "My User Web Root". But http:localhost:80/~myuser/ gets me a "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server".

I have tried working with different answers for the same problem on this site, but none of them seems to work. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: 1. you can use it without `:80` because that's the default port! 2. did you replace `myuser` with your user name?

Comment: make sure LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so uncomented on the apache configuration file and the module loaded. you are facing problem due to disable user mod dir.  Read more: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html

Comment: @csabinho Yes I'm trying to access localhost/~mfeskildsen/ , which is my user. The port number I just added to show what port I was using, since I think I changed it from 8080 to 80 in another guide.

Comment: @SMJobayerAlam I already uncommented the LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file. Do I need to otherwise activate the module somehow?

Comment: @MikkelFiilEskildsen check phpinfo(): and you will see whether this module loaded or not. make a php file using <?php phpinfo(); ?> code and search for mod_userdir. if it is exists there you have no problem in your module. you have to check  configuration as per mention here : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338099/php-not-working-after-upgrading-to-os-mojave

Comment: @SMJobayerAlam Looks like I've done everything, but in phpinfo(), the module is not loaded. The LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so  & Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf in the httpd.conf file are both uncommented. I have the file mfeskildsen.conf in /etc/apache2/users which includes the following: <Directory "/Users/mfeskildsen/Sites/">
'AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>'

Comment: I don't know if this is the culprit, but there might be an issue with my apache. When using "apachectl start" I get: (48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Comment: Address already in use means you are using 80 port already.in some cases if you turn off the server and start again rapidly this error happens. it's not problem if you dont have any other service running on port 80. as you have said the module is not showing in phpinfo() you have problem is in your installation. did you check apache error log. also make sure mod_userdir.so file is present on libexec/apache2/ directory. you can reinstall everything from the beginning or use mamp.

Comment: The /var/log/apache2/ folder where the error log should be is empty.. I stopped the other process running at port 80, and reinstalled apache but still no luck. The mod_userdir.so file is in the libexec/apache2/ directory. The module is still not in phpinfo(). Guess I will have to try mamp